# ARM ORR register difference

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, arm

I'm trying to understand [this kernel change](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8404663f81d212918ff85f493649a7991209fa04). It's a `{get,put}_user` function correction, and it includes this fix:

```
 #ifndef __ARMEB__
-   orr r2, r2, r3, lsl #8
+   orr r2, r2, rb, lsl #8
 #else
-   orr r2, r3, r2, lsl #8
+   orr r2, rb, r2, lsl #8
 #endif
```

This means OR the values in `r2` and `r3` and save the result to `r2`.
For the fix, just read the value from `rb` instead of `r3`. (`__ARMEB__` indicates big endian or not.)

So what does happens if this part of the fix hasn't been applied?

Comment: If you selectively skip that hunk the code will be broken. `rb` is defined to be `ip` or `r0` further up. `r3` doesn't seem to contain anything useful at that point so the code would do something random.

Comment: **CONFIG_CPU_USE_DOMAINS** is similar to `__ARMEB__`.  You need to compile for either version the code does not support both.  `__ARMEB__` is defined by the compiler and **CPU_USE_DOMAINS** by Kconfig (you have an armv6+ CPU).  The change is to replace `r3` with either `ip` or `r0` depending on the Kconfig option.  You don't say *why* you want to understand this?  If you just leave it at `r3` and you do the lines above, the code will operate with garbage values.